# Recording of WebSocket connection in jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter-4.0

I was recording a session via Jmeter, in which my recording is failing as JMeterenter needs to create a WebSocket connection, Kindly help me, as the current recording template doesn't provide any sampler for recording WebSocket connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't record a WebSocket session with JMeter. Only HTTP(S).